# Apply fields restriction as an array in Elastic Search

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I've got the following array from ES and I want to apply `fields` option to return only a specified fields. I'm using `ver.0.90` and I used [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/search-request-fields.html) as reference.

```
Array(
    [id] => 103
    [category] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ver] => 1.2/3
                    [status] => OK
                )
        )
)
```

When I specified `$query['fields'] = ['category']`, it works fine. The array structure is always the same and I need only the `ver` value. So I hardcoded the fields array as: `$query['fields'] = ['category'][0]['ver']`. I didn't get the results from ES correctly and also I got the following php error.

```
<div>
    <h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

    <p>Severity: Warning</p>
    <p>Message:  Illegal string offset 'ver'</p>
    <p>Filename: controllers/query_controller.php</p>
    <p>Line Number: 124</p>
</div>
```

Finally I tried specifying the fields as: `$query['fields'] = array('category' => array('ver'));`, but the query didn't execute at all.

Is the above requirement possible to achieve through ES 0.9?